# Equation FROM Grade 2 Maths

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Yesterday I was looking at a question :

(68-48)  =  ____  % 4  =  ____

I am considering they are three equations with two variables. My answer goes as 80 and 20 for the first and second space. What do you people feel?

Let us consider the first space is   x  and second is y 
So, 68-48 = y
    x % 4 = y

So, that also satisfies the answers as 80 and 20. both side of the equation remains the same.

I see people taking just one glance is saying 20 AND 5 as the answer. But that is absolutely wrong. what do you say?

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be 80 and 20.

$64-48=20$

$x$ modulo $4$ $ = 20$ Therefore $x=80$